# Adding member to npm org with CLI

Tags: npm

I need to add a bunch of users to an npm org. Is there a way to do this with the CLI? I can see a way to add users to a team with the CLI, but not to the org itself. An API endpoint might also work for us.

Comment: adduser is an alias for login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it isn't (currently) possible with npm. I managed to write a script that uses the API directly though. https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/orgs/memberships.md